# Headphones not detected on Asus ROG Zephyrus M-GU502

Tags: sound, 20.04, alsa, headphones

I have a **dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04**. The **speakers work just fine** on windows 10, but when I plug the headphone jack into the computer on ubuntu nothing happens, **it doesn't show up in alsamixer** or on the settings menu sound section. The sound keeps coming out from the speakers.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with GU502 and Ubuntu 20.04.  My solution is to use an external usb audio interface, probably overkill if you aren't seriously into sound.  Though before when I ran into the same problem with earlier versions of ubuntu on different hardware, I solved it with a cheap usb audio adaptor on ebay, just a little dongle with headphone and mic jack effectively. Might be something to consider if you don't come across a better solution (though YMMV when it comes to cheap kit from China).